# How to dump into files request/response pairs in Django?

Tags: django, django-views

I want to store (in files) all request/response pairs of views in a Django app.

How to do this?

I could probably use tcpflow, but would prefer to use a Python solution in Django itself rather than external programs like tcpflow (which also requires root privileges, what I dislike).

Comment: Sorry, confused tcpdump and tcpflow. I will edit my question

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/

Comment: another deficiency of tcpflow is that it stores all (or almost all) activity on the server rather than only of my Django app

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/), something like (adapted the example from the doc):

```
def simple_middleware(get_response):
       def middleware(request):
           response = get_response(request)
           # SAVE REQUEST AND RESPONSE HERE
           return response
    return middleware
```

And adding it to the MIDDLEWARE setting.

Comment: This solution has the deficiency that I cannot see request/response headers as is. Instead I have an unordered dict of headers, so their order (and lettercase?) may be other than in the original request. It is not a major problem, but I would prefer the literal HTTP headers without changes

Comment: Then I doubt a Django solution is going to work, maybe something in the webserver that calls Django.